# jmx authentication failed in cassandra (zabbix)

Tags: cassandra, jmx, cassandra-2.0, zabbix

I tried to set up zabbix monitoring for a cassandra cluster using JMX i am getting the following error on the node. Please help me solve this,

In zabbix ui the cassandra host showed me this error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
```

JAVA GATEWAY LOGS

```
2017-06-07 11:57:47.538 [pool-1-thread-1] WARN  com.zabbix.gateway.SocketProcessor - error processing request
com.zabbix.gateway.ZabbixException: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
        at com.zabbix.gateway.JMXItemChecker.getValues(JMXItemChecker.java:97) ~[zabbix-java-gateway-3.0.9.jar:na]
        at com.zabbix.gateway.SocketProcessor.run(SocketProcessor.java:62) ~[zabbix-java-gateway-3.0.9.jar:na]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed! Credentials required
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticationFailure(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.JMXPluggableAuthenticator.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JMXServerUtils$JMXPluggableAuthenticatorWrapper.authenticate(JMXServerUtils.java:257) ~[na:na]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor19.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set a valid username and password in the JMX items. Test username and password using `nodetool`.

Comment: it works correctly when i use the nodetool status. do we set the username and password here?
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password"

Comment: In general yes, but have you set the credentials in all JMX items?

Comment: yes for every parameter  i have pointed it to JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/‌​jmxremote.password"

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "every parameter", but this is not about the JMX configuration in Cassandra. How did you configure credentials in Zabbix?

Comment: I configured the JMX interfaces in the host tab. I gave the ip-address and port. Should i give any username and password in the JMX items in zabbix?

Comment: Of course - if you limit access to JMX so that even `nodetool` cannot connect without the credentials, how could Zabbix sidestep that? Set the proper credentials in JMX items.